# Large numbers rounding off [c#]

Tags: c#, math, double, rounding

I am having some weird issue here. I have a database table which has huge value stored on a column. My application (C#) is reading this value and keeping in a *double* type. This application will insert the same value to another table. Note : I am not doing any calculations/processing on the value read from the first table. It is just kept for updating the second table.

Issue here is, the second table is getting slightly different value than in the first table. Looks like the number is rounding off when I keep in the double type.

Here is an example of values.

Original Value : **18014398509481984**

Value copied to new table : **18014398509482000**

The values looks different, but both are same in reality. I did a google search with ***18014398509481984 - 18014398509482000*** as a search term and it returned result ***0***, which means both are same.

**Questions**:

1 - If both are same, why the second value looks different? I can see ***1984*** turned into ***2000***.

2 - Why the conversion happens?

3 - How can I avoid this type of conversions?

Any help would be great!

Comment: What is the type of the column in the first table ? And in the second table ? Looks like there is a conversion from a big integer (64 bits) to a double, losing precision in the operation, even without any processing.

Comment: "all numbers are equal" - you can easily prove it this way - is a great platform for next election

Comment: and yes, plz try Decimal, and check precision of DB (which type do you use there, btw?) and .Net types to see where conversion may change the value

Comment: Use Windows Calculator and you can see that the numers are not equal.  It's just that Google has the same rounding behavior as your software.  It uses double precision floating point values when the value is too big to fit in a 32-bit integer (apparently).

Comment: Or use http://www.wolframalpha.com/ instead of Google to do math.

Comment: @FWH : Type of column is NUMBER and the database is ORACLE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a `System.Decimal` to store the value from the first table, instead of a `System.Double`.  `System.Double` doesn't seem to contain enough significant digits to store that large of a value accurately.

Comment: Thanks. I will try with decimal type.

Answer (score 3):

A double precision value is accurate only to 15 or 16 decimal digits (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) for an explanation). If you need to store more than this, then you will have to use a different number format. If you want to work with very big integers without losing accuracy, then there are various classes out there to help you like [this one](http://www.codeplex.com/biginteger).

If you're getting a value out of SQL, make sure that your target data type in .NET matches - SQL bigint for C# long for example - to avoid rounding issues like this.

Comment: My tables type is NUMBER and I using Oracle database

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to floating point precision (the large number will use a mantissa an exponent), which means it would essentially be represented as a factional number with a power. Fractional numbers however encounter rounding errors due to floating point arithmetic.

Normally the way round this is to avoid floating point values (try Int64), use a more precise type (Decimal) or account for the error and do an 'approx equal to'.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by 'approx equal to'?

Comment: You could add an extension method to Double, or a static one, that determines if the values are say 0.001% within each other, and if so assume that they are equal.

Obviously you set the threshold at a point with which you are happy.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to store these as floating point numbers?

If not then you could use 64-bit integers instead: [`BIGINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) in the database, and [`long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx)/[`Int64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx) in your app.

These have a range from –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 and no precision/accuracy issues.

Comment: Thanks. But my value will be floating point number. So I guess int64 or long will not be appropriate.